# Necessary condition of $|\sum a_n|=\sum |a_n|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$ in which each entry is positive.

Let $v$ be a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ where $v_k\neq 0$

Suppose $|\sum_{j=1}^n A_{kj} v_j|=\sum_{j=1}^n |A_{kj} v_j|$.

Then, how do i prove that "there exist *nonnegative real numbers* $c_1,...,c_n$ and a nonzero $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $A_{kj}v_j=c_j z$"?

If i take $d_j = \frac{v_j \overline{v_k}}{|v_k|^2}$, then $v_j=d_j v_k$ for all $j$, but i'm not sure if $d_j$'s are all *nonnegative real numbers*..

Comment: What does it mean for a complex number to be positive?  Do you mean that $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @vadim123 Isn't it usual to say 'positive complex number' to mean positive real? If you don't like it, i'll edit it. I just wanted to emphasize that the field is $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: In some contexts we're interested in complex numbers with positive real component (i.e. in the right half-plane of $\mathbb{C}$).  But honestly I've never heard anyone use the term "positive complex number" before in any context.

Comment: Note that $A$ and $v$ are relevant here only for the $n$ numbers $A_{k,j}v_j$. So you might simplify the question by giving just those values a name. Not only could you then remove the (matrices) tag, but you'd be a lot closer to a solution of the problem.

Comment: I don't know in which context you are working on this problem. If it is for research purpose, you may be interested looking at Perron-Frobenius theory, which is quite much all about these kind of objects and relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an (extended) triangle inequality where actually equality holds.  That means that all the elements ($v_j$) are nonnegative multiples of each other.  You could prove this by induction on $n$, or using Cauchy-Schwarz.